# Sequelize: Find Records Based on Associated BelongsToMany Record-- But Still Return All Associated Records?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I've got two belongsToMany models:

```
const apptsModel = db.define('Appts', {
    id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    [.....]
});

const UserDataModel = db.define('UserData', {
    id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true},
    gender: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    name_title: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    name_first: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    name_last: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    [.....]
});

apptsModel.belongsToMany(UserDataModel, {through: 'ApptsToUsers'});
UserDataModel.belongsToMany(apptsModel, {through: 'ApptsToUsers'});
```

I want to do a search that:

1) Finds all appointments for which at least one of the associated users has a particular user id.

2) Returns all the associated users for that appointment.

I've got working sequelize code that does (1):

```
var ret = connectors.Appts.findAll({
    include: [connectors.UserData],
    where: {'$UserData.id$': args.originatingUserID}
}).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
```

...but it only returns the associated user data for the one specified user.  How do I return the data for all the associated users for each appointment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on how to do this yet. This works, so I will post this here for reference purposes.

```
    getAllApptsForCurrentUser(_, args) {
       return Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => {
                //find all appointments and find those for which at least one 
                //participating user is the one specified in originatingUserID
                var appts = connectors.Appts.findAll({
                    include: [{
                        model: connectors.UserData,
                        where: {id: args.originatingUserID}
                    }],
                }).then((res) => res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
                return appts;
            })
            .then(appts => {
                //iterate returned appointments and perform a subquery on each,
                //finding the other participating users
                var arrayOfPromises = [];
                appts.forEach(function (appt) {
                    arrayOfPromises.push(
                        connectors.Appts.findOne({where: {id: appt.id}, order: [['apptDateTime']], include: [ connectors.UserData ] })
                    );
                });
                //Promise.all returns true when all promises passed to it have 
                //returned true, or when one of them returns false
                return Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);
            })
           .then(apptsWithJoinedData => {
               //console.log(apptsWithJoinedData);
               return apptsWithJoinedData;
           })
           .catch((err)=> {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
```

If there's a better way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: I'd also love to know if there is a simpler way to do this in a single query instead of multiple queries.